# How compilers allocate identifers in the memory

Tags: c

i wanne to know ....now i'm trying to program an embedded system wich contain RAM ,ROM, Microprocessor ....

know i can't under stand when i write instructions like :
int x ;
x= 20 ;

When these program is compiled and Burn to the Rom memory  it will be in the operation code ...
my Question :
know when the processor revieve the operation code corresponding to Int x  ; 
the microprocessor will save a memory location at a random address .

now ..when the processor receive the 2nd instruction x=20  ...it will do a move instruction ...but how can the microprocessor know where does it locate the x variable

.......................................................................
i mean ...how the processor knows the addresses of memory locations reserved for variables ?!!!!

Comment: The compiler turns each variable into a memory address.

Comment: And the processor will not know the name of the variable, because it does not need to know. The compiler will use the same memory address for the same variable.

Comment: Read the reference manual of your programmer. Usually there's a compiler flag to output memory map to a report file, where you can see the actual memory location of all symbols. This is very useful when fine control of compile-time memory allocation is required.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the instruction is just a label for the compiler. The compiler then replaces every occasion of x with an address or a register. This depends on the architecture and its optimization possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

When the code is compiled, the variable x will be assigned a memory address. For example, lets say that the compiler decides to use memory address 0x16 for x. The instruction "x = 20;" will be translated into machine code that will say something equivalent to "put 0x14 into the memory byte at address 0x16" (0x14 being the hex value of 20).

The processor itself will have no knowledge of a variable called "x", it will just be told to look for a byte at address 0x16 (according to my example).